# Laravel if type is this or this

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade

I'm having a problem with `@if` syntax.
I want to show some message but it's doesn't work.
It works only on one type. but I need in 3 types.

```
@if($article->type == 'analytic', 'news', 'interview')
SHOW THIS
@endif
```

Comment: You can also do this. But best method is the answer you got .This is just for your info. $article->type == 'analytic' || $article->type == 'news' || $article->type == 'interview'

Comment: first of all, you should start developing laravel by getting simple PHP training. Also, you  can ask PHP questions or discuss in this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use like below

```
@if (in_array($article->type, array("analytic", "news", "interview")))

   SHOW THIS

@endif
```

**Update**

Array can be define also like this which will short your code

```
["analytic", "news", "interview"]
```

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is to show users a certain content based on if the `$article->type` is one of the values you listed i.e. `["analytic", "news", "interview"]`;

You can do this:

```
@if (in_array($article->type, ["analytic", "news", "interview"]))

   SHOW THIS

@endif
```

There are couple of other alternatives as well, but the above is the most performant solution off the top of my head.